# Access - Update Query from Form Values with Multiselect Listbox VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, multi-select

I have an issue that I feel I'm close to solving, but am missing something. I have an unbound form with five objects.

'SSN' is a standard text box.
'Appointment State' is a listbox with multiselect enabled. The source is a table named States.
'Carrier' is a combobox.
'Appointment Status' is a combobox.
'Appt Request Date' is a date field.

Once values are in all five objects, I have a button that runs the code below. I want to pass the values to an update query to be used as criteria.

The fields that are being updated are 'Appointment Status' and 'Appt Request Date'. The other fields are to select the correct record(s).

Currently the code runs, and the update query receives most of the criteria. The only field that does not populate correctly is the 'Appointment State', which I thought would pull from strCriteria.

When the code runs, it asks the user to populate the strCriteria value when it needs to pull from the 'Appointment States' listbox.

I found the code from a site that told how to grab the values from a multiselect listbox and then creates the SQL for a one criteria Select query. I've tried to adapt it as best as I can. The main difference is the SQL build. When I use the original, it works.

My modified code to operate the update query:

```
Private Sub Command35_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Appointment Update Query")

If Me![Appointment State].ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
  For Each varItem In Me![Appointment State].ItemsSelected
     strCriteria = strCriteria & "States.States = " & Chr(34) _
                   & Me![Appointment State].ItemData(varItem) & Chr(34) &  " OR "
  Next varItem
  strCriteria = Left(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 3)
Else
  strCriteria = "States.States Like '*'"
End If
strSQL = "UPDATE [Appointment Query]" _
& " SET [Appointment Query].[Appointment Status] = [Forms].[Appointment Update].[Appointment Status], [Appointment Query].[Appt Request Date] = [Forms]![Appointment Update].[Appt Request Date]" _
& " WHERE ((([Appointment Query].SSN)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[SSN]) AND (([Appointment Query].[Appointment State])=" & strCriteria & ") AND (([Appointment Query].Carrier)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[Carrier]));"

qdf.SQL = strSQL
qdf.Close  

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Appointment Update Query"

Set db = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

The original code:

```
    Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryMultiSelect")
If Me!lstRegions.ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
  For Each varItem In Me!lstRegions.ItemsSelected
     strCriteria = strCriteria & "tblData.Region = " & Chr(34) _
                   & Me!lstRegions.ItemData(varItem) & Chr(34) & "OR "
  Next varItem
  strCriteria = Left(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 3)
Else
  strCriteria = "tblData.Region Like '*'"
End If
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblData " & _
        "WHERE " & strCriteria & ";"
qdf.SQL = strSQL
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMultiSelect"
Set db = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any ideas on how I could get this to work properly?

Debug.Print strSQL:

```
    UPDATE [Appointment Query] SET [Appointment Query].[Appointment Status] = [Forms].[Appointment Update].[Appointment Status], [Appointment Query].[Appt Request Date] = [Forms]![Appointment Update].[Appt Request Date] WHERE ((([Appointment Query].SSN)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[SSN]) AND (([Appointment Query].[Appointment State])=States.States = "AL" OR States.States = "AZ") AND (([Appointment Query].Carrier)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[Carrier]));
```

Debug.Print strCriteria:

```
    States.States = "AL" OR States.States = "AZ"
```

States is the name of the table the state abbreviations are in, and the second States is the field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show us the SQL from your query - I can see no reason why you're trying to use States.State, so I'm suggesting this change but it's really hard to help much more than this right now

```
If Me![Appointment State].ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then
  strCriteria = "IN ("
  For Each varItem In Me![Appointment State].ItemsSelected
     strCriteria = strCriteria & Chr(34) _
                   & Me![Appointment State].ItemData(varItem) & Chr(34) &  ","
  Next varItem
  strCriteria = Left$(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria)-1) & ")" ' Remove last comma
Else
  strCriteria = "= """ & Me![Appointment State] & """"
End If
```

> EDIT: Updated SQL Statement with double quotes

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Appointment Query]" _
& " SET [Appointment Query].[Appointment Status] = [Forms].[Appointment Update].[Appointment Status], [Appointment Query].[Appt Request Date] = [Forms]![Appointment Update].[Appt Request Date]" _
& " WHERE ((([Appointment Query].SSN)=""" & [Forms]![Appointment Update].[SSN] & """) AND (([Appointment Query].[Appointment State]) " & strCriteria & _
") AND (([Appointment Query].Carrier)=""" & [Forms]![Appointment Update].[Carrier] & """));"
```

Comment: I tried to insert your code, but it did not work. I played around with it and got it to output strCriteria as: "AL" Or "AZ" with:         `If Me![Appointment State].ItemsSelected.Count > 0 Then  
      For Each varItem In Me![Appointment State].ItemsSelected  
         strCriteria = strCriteria & Chr(34) _  
                       & Me![Appointment State].ItemData(varItem) & Chr(34) & " OR "  
      Next varItem  
      strCriteria = Left(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 3)  
   Else  
      strCriteria = "= """ & Me![Appointment State] & """"  
   End If`

Comment: I apologize for the jumbled mess, trying to figure out how to properly format comments...       With the edits so far, the code does run and passes the fields to the query criteria. There is an issue though as it is not updating the correct number of rows. If one state value is selected, it appears to pull the correct record(s). If two are used, it is pulling more records than it should be.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the text fields not having quote marks? I'm not sure how to integrate them with a bracketed field... I tried a few different ways but it threw an error each time.

Comment: Update your code and the resulting Debugs above whenever you make changes so we can see what's happening. I'll update the strSQL statement with double quotes in my last answer

Comment: Here is what I get now, strCriteria and strSQL respectively:      `"AL" Or "AZ"     
UPDATE [Appointment Query]     SET [Appointment Query].[Appointment Status] ="Pending", [Appointment Query].[Appt Request Date] =[Forms]![Appointment Update].[Appt Request Date]     WHERE ((([Appointment Query].SSN)="999999999") AND (([Appointment Query].[Appointment State])="AL" Or "AZ" ) AND (([Appointment Query].Carrier)="ASI"));`  
When run with a single state, it correctly pulls 1 record to update. When two states are selected, it pulls 31 records, there is only 2.

Comment: If you're still getting "OR" in your strCriteria then you're not using my new code that uses "IN" clause - also I updated the strSQL clause to remove "=" after Appointment.State

Comment: After I run the query with one state value with the form and VBA, I can manually change the state values directly on the query in design mode to "AL" Or "AZ" and it pulls the correct two records.

Comment: I replaced that my If statement with yours and removed the = sign you removed in the strSQL clause and it worked perfectly! I don't really understand why the Or statement didn't work, but that's beside the point. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Excellent. You can use an OR statement but it would have to repeat the whole `[Appointment Query].[Appointment State])="<state>"` statement for every State, and then separate them each with "OR"s. Would make for a very long string

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To start with you need spaces between your concatenated strings in SQL - I just added a space before SET and WHERE. Do you get an error message?

Can you Debug.print strSQL?

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Appointment Query]" _
& " SET [Appointment Query].[Appointment Status] = [Forms].[Appointment Update].[Appointment Status], [Appointment Query].[Appt Request Date] = [Forms]![Appointment Update].[Appt Request Date]" _
& " WHERE ((([Appointment Query].SSN)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[SSN]) AND (([Appointment Query].[Appointment State])=strCriteria) AND (([Appointment Query].Carrier)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[Carrier]));"
```

Also it looks like you don't close the qdf before you update the SQL.

```
qdf.SQL = strSQL
qdf.Close
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Appointment Update Query"
```

This is also going to break the query with how you've built strCriteria

```
(([Appointment Query].[Appointment State])=strCriteria)
```

And if any of your individual fields are text fields you're going to need to wrap them in escaped double quotes

Comment: Can you Debug.Print strCriteria before you use it - and post it as an edit in your post above (do same with strSQL)

Comment: I made the edits you suggested and updated them in the code above. I added the debug.print you requested as well.

Comment: Start with - Change `& "OR "` to `& " OR "`

Comment: This is a problem  `[Appointment Query].[Appointment State])=States.States` - what are you trying to compare - where did the States.States table/field come from? Is that what you want to use in your criteria - or are you using the [Appointment State] field?

Comment: I was just following the example in the second code I posted, which is the one I found and edited. The States.States is the table and field name that houses the states that [Appointment State] references. I need the value(s) selected in that listbox to equal a value in [Appointment Query].[Appointment State].

Comment: Is `[Appointment Query].` a table or a query that is joined to a `States` table? Does ` [Appointment State]` have abbreviated state names in it?

Comment: Also important to know - are [SSN] and [Carrier] text fields or numeric? If the're text, you're going to have to wrap the Form fields in double quotes as well

Comment: [Appointment Query] is a query, there is a field in the query titled [Appointment State] (I realize I need to get away from using the same name in multiple objects) that uses the [States] table as a source, which are abbreviated state names.        [SSN] is numeric, [Carrier] is text. Everything seems to be working fine except that I need the states selected in the [Appointment State] listbox on the form to pull over to the [Appointment Query Update] as "AR" OR "CA", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something with not using the variable **strCriteria**, you are using the literal text.

What you have now:

```
"WHERE ((([Appointment Query].SSN)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[SSN]) AND (([Appointment Query].[Appointment State])=strCriteria) AND (([Appointment Query].Carrier)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[Carrier]));"
```

To use the variables contents you need to **escape** it as part of your query, like this:

```
"WHERE ((([Appointment Query].SSN)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[SSN]) AND (([Appointment Query].[Appointment State])=" & strCriteria & ") AND (([Appointment Query].Carrier)=[Forms]![Appointment Update].[Carrier]));"
```

Also, as dbmitch noticed you may need a space before your **WHERE** as well.

Comment: I changed the code based on your and dbmitch's advice. When I run the code now it asks me to input the parameters for States.States. I do not get any actual errors other than that.

Comment: Can you do a debug.print of the sql statement? Perhaps seeing the query to be executed will help clarify things.

Comment: I've added it to the bottom of the question.